# Is there any primary literature addressing p-values and their relevance/irrelevance to in non-linear regressions?

Tags: references, p-value, nonlinear-regression

I am running a series of non-linear regressions (exponential and logarithmic) and came across [this blog post](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/why-are-there-no-p-values-for-the-variables-in-nonlinear-regression) from Minitab's statistician. I delved further and found [this Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148469/how-should-one-assess-model-fit-for-non-linear-regression), which was helpful. However, I am wondering if anyone knows of some literature supporting not reporting p-values along with the other results of the regression? P-values are ubiquitous in my field and not reporting them requires a reference, despite the logical explanation for it.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a Minitab specific question - perhaps that tag should be removed? Or is it there because you're querying the default setting in Minitab? It seems to me that this Q touches on a more general, underlying statistical issue

Comment: +1: that blog post is very confusing, especially because it advocates computing confidence intervals--and those can almost always be used for hypothesis testing!