# Which mathematical test do I need to use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I have a dataset showing the yearly stock returns for two investment styles (growth and value investing) as well as a column showing the difference between the returns for each year. I have attached a picture below.

I want to do a test to see if the difference is significant for each individual year, such that the test fills out the area highlighted in blue.

Which test do I use? And if I use that test, what is the Excel command I need?

[image: Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 4):

This seems misguided to me, but perhaps more importantly you *cannot* test if the two strategies are different in each individual year with this data.

To simplify this a bit: you only have one data point for each strategy in each year, but testing for a difference requires a set of data points so that you can compare the averages (usually the mean). If you had data for each of the strategies from each year *from many different countries*, for example, you would be able to test whether the strategies are different. I would still not recommend doing so, however! There are almost certainly better ways to address your underlying question.

I would strongly recommend reading more about hypothesis testing, statistical significance and p-values before proceeding. There are a number of relevant threads on this site, including:

[Why is "statistically significant" not enough?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79289/why-is-statistically-significant-not-enough)

[What is the meaning of p values and t values in statistical tests?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests)

[When to use Fisher and Neyman-Pearson framework?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23142/when-to-use-fisher-and-neyman-pearson-framework/51823#51823)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @dakofsta Sure thing!

Comment: Since I'm using this for my dissertation, I would like to use some form of statistical test on the whole dataset. I could do a one tailed T test to see if the averages for both means are significantly different, but are there any other tests you would recommend? I know it is cheesy but I get additional marks for using statistical tests in the data

Comment: @dakofsta You shouldn't do that because data points in time series are not independent, which is an assumption in t-tests (and many other simple hypothesis tests). I recommend searching this site, because this has almost certainly been addressed before here. But if you cannot find an answer, post this as a new question with a plot of your two time series.

Comment: I've tried to find the answer all day and haven't found any useful tests :(

Comment: @dakofsta Post a new question, as I said.