# Large sample - statistical significance with minimal differences

Tags: p-value, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, group-differences

**Small disclosure**

I am doing a course that requires learning statistics but it is not my field of expertise so I may make several mistakes, apologies in advance. Also, I will add some background as suggested, but the question is at the end of the post if someone does not want to read everything.

**The Dataset**

I have a large dataset I got from Kaggle with 8000 observations of different individuals. Each individual has 4 binomial attributes (so 1 or 0), i.e. Male (1) or Female (0). There are 5 other columns with continuous variables, i.e one is "average number of characters per post".

**What I am trying to understand**

I wanted to see if for each of these continuous variables there were significant differences among the different groups (so for each attribute).

**Process**

This is where I am less confident about. I thought it would make sense to do the non-parametric Mann-Whitney U Test to compare each group. However, since I am comparing 4 pairs of categories simultaneously, I thought that it would be sensible to adjust the obtained p-values to prevent an increased risk of committing a type 1 error. So I thought of using the Bonferroni correction (if this makes sense...)

**The results**

So I decided to start comparing Group A and Group B for the category "Average Number per Posts". The Mann-Whitney Test gives me the following statistic and p-value: **Statistics=-25707067.000, p=0.000**

The problem is that when I look at the data, this result seems to be very far fetched, here are some descriptive statistics and a box plot:

[image]

[image]

For me, the groups are almost identical, I would have guessed that I would not have found grounds to reject the null hypothesis.

**Question**

I am a bit lost trying to understand the reason behind these results. **With such a large sample, can these minor differences give a significant p-value**? I guess that statistical significance does not mean that something is relevant in real life but are these results possible or most likely a consequence of a mistake I made in the process? Should I have done something different?

**Possible mistakes?**

1. Result of a bad study design and statistical process
2. Result of bad programming (this will be impossible for you to determine but I guess it's possible)
3. Correctly computed but misinterpretation of the results
4. Combination of the previous or other

Any way, thanks and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "statistically significant" not enough?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79289/why-is-statistically-significant-not-enough) See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/79304/28500) in particular.

Comment: Yes! that is awesome, thanks EdM. Thank you very much.