# Calculating power function for ANOVA

Tags: anova, t-test, statistical-power

There are several functions in R to calculate the power of a test, for example, the pwr-functions of the `pwr` package.

My question is how we get this function for ANOVA (`pwr.anova.test`)?

I know that
\begin{align}
1-\beta &= P(H1|H1)   \\
        &= P(F>F_{1-\alpha,k-1,N-k})  \\
        &= 1-P(F\le F_{1-\alpha,k-1,N-k}) \\
        &= 1-P(MQE/MQR\le F_{1-\alpha,k-1,N-k}) \\
~  \\
        &= 1-P\bigg(n k \bigg(\frac{^{\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2}/_{(k-1)}}
                                   {^{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2}/_{k(n-1)}} - 
                              f^2\!+\!f^2\bigg) \le F_{1-\alpha,k-1,N-k}\bigg)  \\
~  \\
~  \\
        &= 1-P\bigg(nk\bigg(\frac{^{\sum (\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2}/_{(k-1)}}
                                 {^{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.}^2)}/_{k(n-1)}} - \frac{^{\sum(µ_i-µ)^2}/_k}{\sigma^2}\bigg)\le F_{1-\alpha,k-1,N-k}-nkf^2\bigg)  \\
~  \\
        &= ???...??? \\
        &= 1-P(F_{k-1,N-k}\le F_{1-\alpha,k-1,N-k}-knf^2)  \\
        &=
\end{align}

```r
p.body =  pf(qf(\alpha, k-1, (n-1)*k, low=FALSE), k-1, (n-1)k, 
                k*n*f^2, low=FALSE)
```

With $f^2$ the effect;
$knf^2$ the non-centrality parameter; and
$\sigma^2$ the error variance within groups;

But what does the function which has a $F_{k-1, N-k}$ distribution look like? It has to be the (variance between groups/df) / (variance within groups/df)$-knf^2$, but how can I write these so that I see the distribution? In my calculation I did not see it. I have never found the exact way how to get to this formula. Maybe you can help.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking (I'm not proficient in English but usually I easily understand mathematical and R questions)

Comment: Your question is still not clear to me but I'm under the impression that from one hand you are interested in the [noncentral F-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_F-distribution), but you have a strange notation ($-knf^2$ sounds like *"minus" $knf^2$*). See also the help of the F-distribution in R by typing `?df`.

Comment: I still don't understand. I can try to explain the power calculation in details, would it answer to your question ?

Comment: Done. Now could you precise your question ?

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot Stéphane. Thats what i mean, ok not exaktly but near. You said that $F \sim F_{m-l,n-m}$ thats clear  but if we write $F=\frac{SS_T/(I-1)}{SS_E/((n-I)}$ like in [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) than we will get $F=\frac{\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2/(k-1)}{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2/k*(n-1)}$. Now if we look at the probability $1-P(F<=F_{k-1,n-k}) = 1-P(\frac{n*\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2/(k-1)}{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2/k*(n-1)}<=F_{k-1,n-k})$ Am I right so far? Now we can add $f^2$ and remove $f^2$ ($f^2$ the effect)

Comment: $= 1-P(n*k(\frac{\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2/(k-1)}{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2/(n-1)})<=F_{k-1,n-k,1-\alpha}) =1-P(n*k(\frac{\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2/(k-1)}{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2/(n-1)}-f^2+f^2)<=F_{k-1,n-k,1-\alpha}) =1-P(n*k(\frac{\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2/(k-1)}{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2/(n-1)}-\frac{\sum(\frac{1}{k}*(µ_i-µ)^2)}{\sigma^2}+\frac{\sum(\frac{1}{k}*(µ_i-µ)^2)}{\sigma^2})<=F_{k-1,n-k,1-\alpha})$ like in [link](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html) for n=n1=...=nk.

Comment: $=1-P(n*k(\frac{\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2/(k-1)}{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2/(n-1)}-\frac{\sum(\frac{1}{k}*(µ_i-µ)^2)}{\sigma^2})<=F_{k-1,n-k,1-\alpha}-n*k\frac{\sum(\frac{1}{k}*(µ_i-µ)^2)}{\sigma^2})$. Let us only look at the left side: $n*k(\frac{\sum(\bar{x}_{i.}-\bar{x}_{..})^2/(k-1)}{\sum\sum(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{i.})^2/(n-1)}-\frac{\sum(\frac{1}{k}*(µ_i-µ)^2)}{\sigma^2})$ how can I write this to see the $F_{k-1,n-k} distribution?

Comment: Sorry but there are many unclear points. For example your final question, what do you mean by "seeing" a Fisher distribution ?

Comment: What I mean is how can I rewrite the sums so that I will have something like $\frac{*/(k-1)}{**/n-k}$ because that is what I need for Fisher distribution. Or did I make any mistakes befor the final calculation?

Comment: I just want to make a small point here. In your last paragraph, you state "It has to be the (variance between groups/df) / (variance within groups/df)". This is an easy misunderstanding. It isn't the *variance*, it would be the *sum of squares* within... etc.

Answer (score 5):

### Power of F-tests for Gaussian linear models

#### General $F$-test

Any Gaussian linear model can be written $\boxed{Y=\mu+\sigma G}$ where $G$ has the standard normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu$ is assumed to belong to a linear subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Usually, the theory of Gaussian linear models treat them with the $Y=X\beta+\sigma G$ writing, corresponding to $W=\text{Im}(X)$. There are good reasons for that but the underlying geometry is clearer with the $\boxed{Y=\mu+\sigma G}$  treatment.

The so-called "ANOVA test" is a particular test of a F-test for a null hypothesis $H_0\colon\{\mu \in U\}$ where $U\subset W$ is a linear subspace. Actually the F-test exactly coincides with the likelihood-ratio test in this situation, and it is based on the  Fisher statistic
$$
F  = \frac{{\Vert P_Z Y\Vert}^2/(m-\ell)}{{\Vert P_W^\perp Y\Vert}^2/(n-m)}, 
$$
where  $Z=U^\perp \cap W$ is the orthogonal complement of $U$ in $W$, and denoting $m=\dim(W)$ and $\ell=\dim(U)$.

Obviously $\boxed{P_Z Y = P_Z \mu + \sigma P_Z G}$ and
$\boxed{P_W^\perp Y = \sigma P_W^\perp G}$.

**When $H_0\colon\{\mu \in U\}$ is true** then $P_Z \mu = 0$ and therefore
$$
F  = \frac{{\Vert P_Z G\Vert}^2/(m-\ell)}{{\Vert P_W^\perp G\Vert}^2/(n-m)} \sim F_{m-\ell,n-m}
$$
has the Fisher $F_{m-\ell,n-m}$ distribution. Consequently, from the  classical relation between the Fisher distribution and the Beta distribution, $R^2 \sim {\cal B}(m-\ell, n-m)$.

**In the general situation** we have to deal with $P_Z Y = P_Z \mu + \sigma P_Z G$ when $P_Z\mu \neq 0$. In this general case one has ${\Vert P_Z Y\Vert}^2 \sim \sigma^2\chi^2_{m-\ell}(\lambda)$, where $\chi^2_{m-\ell}(\lambda)$ is [the noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with $m-\ell$ degrees of freedom and  noncentrality parameter $\boxed{\lambda=\frac{{\Vert P_Z \mu\Vert}^2}{\sigma^2}}$, and then
$\boxed{F \sim  F_{m-\ell,n-m}(\lambda)}$ [noncentral Fisher distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_F-distribution). To compute $P_Z\mu$, note that $P_Z = P_W - P_U$ and $P_W\mu=\mu$, hence the only thing to compute is $P_U \mu$.

#### Power of the $F$-test

The power of the $F$-test depends on the significance level $\alpha$ which is chosen by the user. The critical value $c$ of the test is the value for which $\Pr_0(F>c)=1-\alpha$ where $\Pr_0$ denotes the probability under the null $H_0$. The power is then $\Pr(F>c)=1-\alpha$ where $\Pr$ denotes the probability under the unknown parameters. As we have seen, $\Pr$ only depends on $\lambda$, $n$, $m$ and $l$.

#### R code

The **effect size** in this situation is $\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{n}}$, and it is more usual to take the effect size rather than the non-centrality parameter $\lambda$ as an input of the power. Thus I have written the following R function which returns the power using the effect size as an argument rather than the noncentrality parameter.

```r
# alpha : significance level eff : effect size ; n : sample size ; m :
# number of parameters of the model ; l : number of parameters of the
# submodel H0 ;
Power <- function(alpha, eff, n, m, l) {
    df1 <- m - l
    df2 <- n - m
    c <- qf(1 - alpha, df1, df2)
    lambda <- eff^2 * n
    pow <- pf(c, df1, df2, ncp = lambda, lower.tail = FALSE)
    return(pow)
}
```

##### Example

```r
Power(alpha = 5/100, eff = 0.5, n = 48, m = 5, l = 4)
## [1] 0.92303
```

#### The case of ANOVA

The `pwr.anova.test()` function of the `pwr` package calculates power of ANOVA for the balanced case only. For example, when there are $3$ groups, $4$ observations per group, the power for $\alpha=5\%$ and for an effect size of $0.5$ is

```r
library(pwr)
pwr.anova.test(3, 4, 0.5, 5/100)
## 
##      Balanced one-way analysis of variance power calculation 
## 
##               k = 3
##               n = 4
##               f = 0.5
##       sig.level = 0.05
##           power = 0.24088
## 
## NOTE: n is number in each group
```

With the general notations of the $F$-test, here $U$ is a one-dimensional subspace corresponding to the assumptions that all group means are equal. The space $W$ has the same dimension as there are groups, here $3$. Thus using my function one get the power as follows:

```r
Power(alpha = 5/100, eff = 0.5, n = 12, m = 3, l = 1)
[1] 0.24088
```

Comment: I have no clue what variables $P_Z$ and $P_W$ are. Please give definitions.

Comment: @matus $P_U$ is the projector on the vector space $U$.

Comment: +1, however you can use the `pwr` package to compute power for the case of unequal group sizes (despite what its documention implies). For the `n` parameter, you take the average number of observations in each group (I know, unintuitive, but under the hood `pwr` uses only the total sample size to find power). Importantly, for the `f` parameter you take care of computing correctly the effect size, which will be different if the group sizes are equal or unequal. I give an example here of how to compute the correct effect size: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/637646/164936